# Export - import iPhone keyboard shortcuts as text file?

Tags: iphone, settings

On an iPhone, if you go to `Settings > General > Keyboard > Shortcuts` you can define text shortcuts that expand into longer words.

Is it possible to export this list of shortcuts in a single text file?
Is it possible to import a text file to be used as shortcuts?

This could be useful to configure the same shortcuts on an iPhone and a Mac, on 2 iPhones, to make a text backup, to make quick edits on a textfile…

Answer (score 1):

From dastrobu:

There is an unofficial command line tool, which does exactly what you want, its called shortcuts. You can install it via homebrew

```
brew install rodionovd/taps/shortcuts
```

You can list your current replacements via

```
shortcuts read
```

You can import new ones via:

```
shortcuts import <input.plist>
```

There are also these commands:

```
shortcuts create <shortcut> <new phrase>
shortcuts update <shortcut> <phrase>
shortcuts delete <shortcut>
```

Source: [How to export Text replacements from the Keyboard System Preference from shell?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287338/how-to-export-text-replacements-from-the-keyboard-system-preference-from-shell)

Comment: The original question was about iPhone environment: see the title, flags & content.