# How to export Text replacements from the Keyboard System Preference from shell?

Tags: macos, automator, system-settings, plist

There are a few users here that use the same replacement text between several machines. We'd like to be able to sync up the replacement table between the systems.

Right now the manual way of doing this consists of selecting all items from System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Text entries on the table below this tab and then drag them out to Finder. Here's the table I'm talking about:
[image: example]

This creates a plist that can then be shared and dragged back onto this table for importation.

I suspect that there's a way to manually capture the plist or a portion of this configuration wherever it exists and then simply set up a sync script that keeps us all in sync every day.

EDIT: For what it's worth, I did a little digging and found that these values are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`. If you look you'll see these stored in the `NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems` key.

I found that you can pull out these keys with the following command:
`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems" ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`

So now it's going to be a matter of storing these and reinserting them into another system's plist key.

Any ideas on how to do this manually from the shell so as to be able to automate?

Comment: Not really answering the question, but maybe addressing the underlying need: iCloud sync of text replacements should be fixed in iOS 11 and MacOS 10.13 High Sierra. https://daringfireball.net/linked/2017/09/27/text-replacements-moving-to-cloudkit

Comment: Thanks, yes, I should have noted that myself. This is helped (although I would still like to do it). Funny enough it seems to have come as a response from a feature request that I made to Apple. LOL. I'll give you an up vote, although I would still like to leave this around as not yet answered for an actual answer if it exists...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an unofficial command line tool, which does exactly what you want, its called [shortcuts](https://github.com/rodionovd/shortcuts).
As mentioned on GitHub, you can install it via homebrew

```
brew install rodionovd/taps/shortcuts
```

and then list your current replacements via

```
shortcuts read
```

and add new ones via

```
shortcuts import <input.plist>
shortcuts create <shortcut> <new phrase>
shortcuts update <shortcut> <phrase>
shortcuts delete <shortcut>
```

for details, see the [documentation](https://github.com/rodionovd/shortcuts#usage).

Comment: Unfortunately, it no longer seems to work. https://github.com/rodionovd/homebrew-taps/issues/1 documents failures since 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Simply press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> (select all)  on the text replacement entries, drag them to desktop, send that file in email, drag and drop it back to the text replacement in the settings on the new MacBook, done.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the `.plist` files I have on my system no longer appear to be editable XML files. But the command-line tool `PlistBuddy` which you mentioned in the question can help manage these files, too.

I found a couple of tutorials for how to use it:

- [What is PlistBuddy?](https://medium.com/@marksiu/what-is-plistbuddy-76cb4f0c262d)
- [How To Manage Plist Files With PlistBuddy](https://www.marcosantadev.com/manage-plist-files-plistbuddy/)

Just to be on the safe side, I copied my `.GlobalPreferences.plist` before attempting to modify it.

This tool has an interactive mode. The following demonstrates a brief session - the lines with `Command:`  are the prompts from PlistBuddy, and the rest of that line is a command I typed in.

```
bash:tripleee$ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
Command: Print :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems
Array {
    Dict {
        replace = omw
        with = On my way!
        on = 1
    }
Command: Add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems:1:replace string hello
Command: Add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems:1:with string goodbye 
Command: Add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems:1:on integer 1 
Command: Print :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems
Array {
    Dict {
        replace = omw
        with = On my way!
        on = 1
    }
    Dict {
        replace = hello
        on = 1
        with = goodbye
    }
}
Command: exit
```

(The arrays are apparently zero-based; it will complain if you try to `add` into a position that is already occupied, though you can use `set` to change an existing value.)

You want to `save` if you are happy with the results, otherwise just `exit` and start over.

There is an `import` command but my impression is that it only supports reading a `string` into a single value. There is also a `merge` command but it requires another `.plist` file if I'm reading this correctly.

For a nontrivial import, I would create a simple shell script like this.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist <<\____done
delete :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems
add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems array
add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems:0:replace string moo
add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems:0:with string bar
add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems:0:on integer 1
add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems:1:replace string baz
add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems:1:with string quux
add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems:1:on integer 1
add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems:2:replace string ick
add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems:2:with string don\'t
add :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems:2:on integer 1
print :NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems
___done
```

Notice that any single quotes in the replacement string have to be backslash-escaped. Similarly, any literal backslashes will need to be doubled. I don't know if there are other special characters; I didn't stumble into any in my testing. The maximum of the replacement string appears to be 459 characters. (Weirdly, you get "Unrecognized Command" if you exceed this.)

Save this in a text file like `/tmp/uplist` and run it with `sh /tmp/uplist`. (You can't use TextEdit for this; remarkably, it does not actually support writing plain text files.)

Notice that there is no `save` in this example; you will want to verify that it seems to do the correct thing before you replace the `print` command on the last line with just `save` and rerun the script.

When you run the script, it will unattractively print the `Command:`  prompt as many times as you have commands in the file. You might want to add a redirection `>/dev/null` once you are satisfied that it works acceptably. Before you do that, check that there are no error messages mixed in there, especially if you have experimented with nontrivial changes.

Bewilderingly, the `dict` data type is output in whatever order the system decides; don't be upset if the `on` appears before the `with` in individual `Dict` entries.

[macOS Force User Global Preferences Reread To Refresh GUI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338576/macos-force-user-global-preferences-reread-to-refresh-gui) seems to indicate that the change will only take effect after a reboot.

---

I found that this preference now also seems to live in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Keyboard-Settings.extension/Data/tmp/Text Substitutions.plist`, which is a plain XML file, but so far, I'm not sure which is the master and which is some kind of mirror location.

Answer (score -1):

If it helps, if all that you have is a non-bootable backup of the old system, simply grabbing the entries from the .GlobalPreferences.plist manually may not work, as the entries are formatted differently there. You may need to do some find and replace so that

```
        <dict>
        <key>on</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>replace</key>
        <string>shruggie</string>
        <key>with</key>
        <string>¯\_(ツ)_/¯</string>
    </dict>
```

becomes

```
        <dict>
        <key>shortcut</key>
        <string>shruggie</string>
        <key>phrase</key>
        <string>¯\_(ツ)_/¯</string>
    </dict>
```