# macOS Force User Global Preferences Reread To Refresh GUI

Tags: macos, ui

The user global preferences file (High Sierra, Mojave)
~`/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`
contains a user's GUI preferences.

The preferences are read at login, but, how do I force the
system to reread these preferences and refresh the GUI
after I place a new value in this prefs plist without requiring a logout/login?

I am looking for a less intrusive way of updating the GUI. I realize it is possible to force this, using osascript utility through System Events command. However, this approach requires a change to "Security & Privacy" preferences (or you will have to respond to a dialog box alerting you of the attempt.) I just want to do this in the "background".
For example:

```
prefs="$HOME/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist"
value="Dark"
defaults write  "$prefs" AppleInterfaceStyle "$value"
```

This bit of code can run quietly and will only take effect when the user next logs in.

I was hoping, perhaps, there was a running process that could receive a signal to refresh the GUI (other Unix systems allow a SIGUSR1 signal sent to the window manager to reset GUI.)

Comment: I would upvote twice if I could!

Comment: BTW, you can use any of the following to access the global preferences: `-g`, `NSGlobalDomain`, `.GlobalPreferences` or `"Apple Global Domain"` and it will get you there. Granted, that doesn't answer your question, but it may be useful so you don't have to store the value in `prefs` like you are.